# Ionic Ion-Button icon-only

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I'm very new in Ionic2 or Ionic at all. I set up a new project and want to design a small menu at the bottom of the foot of my page. I didn't do anything else on this project and trying to imitate the steps of a tutorial video. but when I use the icon-only directive on a button the background of the button only becomes a bit smaller. The background doesn't disappear.

```
<ion-content class="bg-image" padding>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <button ion-button icon-only>
      <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button ion-button icon-only>
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Here's my code. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding a `clear` attribute should give the result you want if i understand correctly:

```
<ion-content class="bg-image" padding>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <button ion-button icon-only clear>
      <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button ion-button icon-only clear>
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Answer (score 17):

For Ionic 4 - `<ion-button fill="clear">`

You can use the fill property now, e.g:

```
<ion-button (click)="onClick()" fill="clear">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="home"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 4):

For Ionic 4:

```
...
    <ion-button (click)="onClick()">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="home"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
...
```

You can go to this link for more references https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button

Answer (score 1):

```
ionic 4 :

 <ion-button (click)="onClick()" fill="clear">
   <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="home"></ion-icon>
 </ion-button>
```

Comment: Explanation is needed for submitted codes for further information.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26168907)